# DocuSign API: Assigning TemplateRoles Properly

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Using the DocuSign API in C#, I was easily able to get a test envelope through.  Now I'm testing on an envelope with the following diagram.

[image: Docusign Flow]

I know I have to assign a `TemplateRole` for a recipient, but when I'm sending the Email, things go wrong. I assumed by defining multiple roles, each of the items in the signing order would be set up. That for whatever reason does not happen, and instead I get two documents sent out. Depending on what TemplateRoles I include, dummy data will get inserted for the sender name/address as well. I'd like to prevent that.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.EmailSubject = "[DocuSign C# SDK] - Sample Signature Request";

envDef.TemplateId = TemplateID;

TemplateRole DirectorRole = new TemplateRole();
DirectorRole.Email = RecipientEmail;
DirectorRole.Name = RecipientName;
DirectorRole.RoleName = "Director";

TemplateRole TraineeRole = new TemplateRole();
TraineeRole.Email = RecipientEmail;
TraineeRole.Name = "A Trainee";
TraineeRole.RoleName = "Trainee";

List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { DirectorRole, TraineeRole };
envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;

envDef.Status = "sent";
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

You can see I have the option to send to a bulk recipient or individual. I'd like to send to either one or the other. How can I go about doing so? Here's my current code. General examples of how to assign different types of roles would be appreciated since as far as I know, there's not a whole lot of C# example code out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DocuSign [compositeTemplates](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#composite-templates) feature and create envelopes from templates. This is more flexible than using [TemplateRole](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/main/csharp/DocuSign/eSign/Model/TemplateRole.cs).

See this sample [code](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/736280cc43e91752eb64a0221db80896) for creating envelope from a template. It is using the [DocuSign C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

```
      string accountId = Init();


        var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {
            EmailSubject = "Envelope with multiple recipient roles",
            Status = "sent",
            CompositeTemplates = new List<CompositeTemplate>()
            {
                new CompositeTemplate()
                {
                    ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate>()
                    {
                        new ServerTemplate()
                        {
                            TemplateId = "", //CreateTemplate()
                            Sequence = "1"
                        }
                    },
                    InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate>()
                    {
                        new InlineTemplate()
                        {
                            Sequence = "1",
                            Recipients = new Recipients()
                            {
                                Signers = new List<Signer>()
                                {
                                    new Signer()
                                    {
                                        Email = "Janedoe@acme.com",
                                        Name = "Jane Doe",
                                        RecipientId = "1",
                                        RoleName = "Signer1",
                                    },
                                    new Signer()
                                    {
                                        Email = "Bobdoe@acme.com",
                                        Name = "Bob Doe",
                                        RecipientId = "2",
                                        RoleName = "Signer2",
                                    },
                                    new Signer()
                                    {
                                        Email = "DanDoe@acme.com",
                                        Name = "Dan Doe",
                                        RecipientId = "3",
                                        RoleName = "Signer3",
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };


        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

Comment: Just to clarify for any others who might be asking the same question, both methods using either `CompositeTemplate` or `TemplateRole` work without the bulk sender in my template. For now I've removed the bulk send option. The flexibility of `CompositeTemplate` is very useful. I will move to a different discussion about implementing bulk sending should issues continue.

Answer (score 1):

Please show your complete code for creating the `envDef` object.
Are you setting the template ID?

The `RoleName` for each `TemplateRole` object must exactly match the role name in the template.

Each Role defined by the Template must be set. If you decide that you want to start with a Template and then modify it to remove a role, I believe that's possible but you'd need to do it by using composite templates. Instead, I'd recommend you consider having two templates, one with the two roles, one with a single role.

Re sending to a bulk recipient. I'd ask that as a separate question. I suggest you use stepwise-refinement. First get your envelopes working with role substitution.

Then move on to the different question of sending out many different envelopes controlled by a CSV file (bulk send).

Comment: So you're suggesting removing either the bulk send or the individual recipient, and separating them into two separate templates? It seems like that could be causing the issue as far as I can tell. I'd just have to get an admin to change the templates. The role names do match, but I was under the assumption that I could omit the bulk send for example to take a different route for a single individual, but I guess this is not the case.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm suggesting that you first get the template working without the bulk recipient. Then ask a different question on StackOverflow about using a bulk recipient with a template. Bulk recipients require uploading the CSV file, etc. -- they're a different kettle of fish.

Comment: I absolutely got what you meant. Your post was of use for sure. It pointed me in the right direction, and I eventually figured out about the CSV being mandatory even with the diagram that I gave, but I needed more information about template roles as well just to make things clear because C# examples are not particularly easy to find.